# Wireless disconnects and reconnects especially when I download from deluge and firefox

Tags: wireless, firefox, deluge

In general, my wireless connection seems to be working fine but it keeps disconnecting and reconnecting when I start downloading files from deluge and Firefox.

I have tried most of the tweaks and workarounds I could find online in similar questions, but without any success so far. I am a very new Linux user so I would appreciate if somebody told me what I should post (perhaps from my log or something) in order to see if this problem can be solved.

I am running Ubuntu 15.04, and the command "type lshw -C network" gives me the following

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: e0:ca:94:1f:f3:07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.19.0-28-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:17 memory:f6600000-f660ffff

*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 05
   serial: 00:1f:c6:9d:ff:ed
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:29 ioport:a000(size=256) memory:e2c04000-e2c04fff memory:e2c00000-e2c03fff
```

I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: please see this answer here http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/167115 and follow the instructions to provide more info, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of people on the low channels, especially channel 1. You are currently on channel 2.

Try changing your wifi router to use **channel 11** for now.

Other problems may include your wireless router overheating or filling up with logs and having to reset. So, also check your wireless router logs immediately after the problem occurs so you can see if there is any helpful information like a recent reset or reboot.

---

Also, according to [this post here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=164279), you might want to run the following command after suspending to reset wpa_supplicant:

```
systemctl restart wpa_supplicant
```

Comment: I will give it a go and let you know. Many thanks!

Comment: I changed the channel and it seems to be working fine now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Nope, that did not work. As soon as I open youtube I lag and I although I am connected to the wifi the internet connection is not working momentarily. I get all this in the syslog, maybe this helps to understand paste.ubuntu.com/12366736/

Comment: set your bssid to a static number and set your crda  to the correct country in /etc/default/crda then restart network-manager or reboot